# Proof of convergence of series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{n+3}{n+5})^{n^\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have been trying to prove that the following series is convergent:
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{n+3}{n+5})^{n^\frac{3}{2}}$

I have tried applying ratio test, root test to no avail. Wolfram Alpha determines that this series converges from the comparison test, however I am unable to figure out to what one.

Comment: Write $(\frac{n+3}{n+5})^{n^{3/2}}=\left[\left(1+\frac{-2}{n+5}\right)^{-(n+5)/2}\right]^{-2n^{3/2}/(n+5)}$. Note that $\left(1+\frac{-2}{n+5}\right)^{-(n+5)/2}\to e$. So, comparing your series with $\sum e^{-n^{3/2-1}}$ gives you its convergence.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy thanks! As that's basically an answer, would you mind posting it as such?